Is FILEPROPERTY only used for database_files dmv?
I'm trying to mix some queries I created in the past, and some that I stole over the network to give me mount points size and free space together with database size and free space of the files.
Only one thing I can't get done is the Free database space.
select CAST(FILEPROPERTY(mf.name, 'SPACEUSED') AS INT) from sys.database_files mf

This works for a single database. But My query is retrieving data for all dbs in a server. When I change database_files to database_files , it retrieves all rows NULL but the database I am in now (below I am on master):

Is it possible to use that function like that for all the files in Master_files without any crazy loop?
Because when I run the entire query, I obviously get this ( Only the database I am in shows a value ):


The documentation for FILEPROPERTY (Transact-SQL) says (emphasis added):

file_name
Is an expression that contains the name of the file associated with the current database for which to return property information. file_name is nchar(128).

You'd need dynamic SQL for your purpose.
You might be interested in the  the "Size - ServerSpaceUsage.sql" script at https://github.com/aleksey-vitsko/Database-Administrator-Tools by Aleksey Vitsko. Use it to deploy a stored procedure "ServerSpaceUsage" on your server to achieve what you seem to be after.

You can combine your query with sp_msforeachdb, which is an undocumented stored procedure that runs a given SQL statement in all databases.
Here is something that I use for a quick check of space issues in a server:
exec sp_msforeachdb 'use [?]; select ''?'' as DBName, name as FileName, physical_name, size/128.0 as SizeInMB,
size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, ''SpaceUsed'') AS INT)/128.0 AS FreeSpaceMB
FROM sys. database_files'

